# How to move from Activity to Fragment in ViewPage? No view found for id for fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I just started learning android. I have a Activity class and I want to redirects it to a fragment in ViewPage of a Navigation bar?
I try many ways but it don't work. I hope to help!!!
My code:
There is a MainActivity.java has a ViewPager and BottomNavigationView

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView navigationView;
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav);
        mViewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        setUpViewPager();
        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemReselectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onNavigationItemReselected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                if(item.getItemId()== R.id.cld){
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                } else if(item.getItemId()== R.id.tdl){
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }else if(item.getItemId()== R.id.dnr){
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                }else if(item.getItemId()== R.id.us){
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                }

            }
        });

        try {
            Field field = CursorWindow.class.getDeclaredField("sCursorWindowSize");
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(null, 100 * 1024 * 1024); //the 100MB is the new size
        } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    private void setUpViewPager() {
        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), FragmentStatePagerAdapter.BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                switch (position){
                    case 1:
                        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.tdl).setChecked(true);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.dnr).setChecked(true);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.us).setChecked(true);
                        break;
                    default: navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.cld).setChecked(true);
                        break;

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }


}
```

ViewPageApdater class

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public ViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull  FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
        super(fm, behavior);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position){
            case 1: return new ListTodo();
            case 2: return  new dinary_form();
            case 3: return  new UserInfor();
            case 0:
            default: return new Calendar();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

And Activity class I want to move and I have a problem:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a01d3 (com.example.projectminibook:id/view_pager) for fragment ListTodo{bbdabd4 (d10d7649-01eb-4b76-8342-fbf47138d234) id=0x7f0a01d3}

I take id/view_paper from id of ViewPager layout in activitymain. I dont know where wrong

```
public class AddTodo extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               ListTodo fragment = new ListTodo();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.view_pager,fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

ListTodo.java

```
public class ListTodo extends Fragment{
  //mycode
}
```

I hope you can help me. Thank you very much

Comment: hey buddy, i think your problem is that you have only four fragments, & you are trying to get 5 fragments. because of this ```@Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }```          try to return 4 fragments.

Comment: it's not my problem

Answer (score 0):

### Just try below code in `onNavigationItemSelectedListener`

---

```
@Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.cld:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    break;

                case R.id.tdl:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                    break;

                case R.id.dnr:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                    break;

                case R.id.us:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(3);
                    break;

                default:
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

---

### I think your problem will go after update this code in your `MainActivity`. Happy Coding ;)

---

## UPDATE

the upper code also has minor changes & for the `viewPager` please edit your code of `onPageSelected()` method with below code

```
 @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                switch (position){
                    case 1:
                        NavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.tdl);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        NavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.dnr);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        NavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.us);
                        break;
                    default: 
                        NavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.cld);
                        break;

                }
            }
```

---

Comment: when i change the above code the viewpaper cannot setCurrentItem and it returns null data

Comment: please refer updated code. if i am not wrong, now your error will be gone.

Comment: I don't know if it bothers you? But my problem is that I can't redirect from 1 Activity page to 1 fragment which is a viewpager of navigationbar, the redirection between navigation fragments (fragment) still works properly. Since I'm just a student and just starting to learn, things are difficult for me, I'm looking forward to solving this problem

Comment: if i am not wrong you are trying to navigate from one fragment to another using bottomNavigation. but you are not navigating properly. Am i right or not?

Comment: Maybe because I used the wrong word, you don't understand what I mean. i have class AddTodo extends AppCompatActivity and when i press save button to redirect through ListTodo() which is a fragment of ViewPage of Navigation bar i get error : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a01d3 (com.example. projectminibook:id/view_pager) for fragment ListTodo{bbdabd4 (d10d7649-01eb-4b76-8342-fbf47138d234) id=0x7f0a01d3}
The code of each class I have put above.

Comment: I am adding another answer for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

### you are not directly navigate to that fragment which is in the another activity. that's why you are getting this `illegalArgumentException` error.

> 1). you have to navigate to that activity first.

---

> 2). you have to check that the navigated activity is where come from. **for this you can use Intent's put extra method.**

---

> 3). if the **intent.put extra has any value** then you have to navigate from one fragment to another. In your case, you have to navigate from calender fragment to ListTodo fragment in main activity.

```
public class AddTodo extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button btnCancel = findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               startActivity(new Intent(activity, MainActivity.class).putExtra("from","AddTodo"));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

### & in `MainActivity`'s onCreate method you have to code like this.

---

```
String comeFrom = getIntent().getStringExtra("from");
if (!(comeFrom.equals("") || comeFrom.isEmpty()) && comeFrom.equals("AddTodo")){
    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1); //because your list todo fragment is 2nd fragment in your viewpager
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your enthusiasm, it's very helpful for a beginner like me ^^

Comment: is this solved your problem? if yes then please upvote & tick mark to right. it will be helpfull for me. HAPPY CODING ;)